# Live video stream player for HTTP streaming server

Tags: browser, video-streaming, mime, multipart-mixed-replace

I have a video streaming server that provides an HTTP API for live video streams. A stream is sent as `multipart/x-mixed-replace` so each video frame is delimited with a certain boundary string like `--DigifortBoundary` for instance. Also each frame comes with its own `Content-Type` header which, according to this particular streaming server's documentation, can be one of these:

- image/jpeg
- image/wavelet
- video/mpeg
- video/h263
- video/h264

Example of a stream:

```
--DigifortBoundary
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 35463

JPEG_DATA
JPEG_DATA
..
..
..
JPEG_DATA
--DigifortBoundary
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 34236

JPEG_DATA
JPEG_DATA
..
..
.. JPEG_DATA
```

The problem is, I need to embed a video player in an HTML page but I could not find any player that supports the `multipart/x-mixed-replace` content type or even streaming via HTTP. I know the flash video players out there usually support [RTMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol) or [RTSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol), but I've never heard of a player that supports HTTP video streaming.

Do you know any web video player that can do it?

Comment: If you your distribution doesn't mind installing a plugin you can install the vlc plugin for chrome or firefox.

Answer (score 0):

on the client side VLC and Firefox can doit - probably lots more.
On the server side:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG#M-JPEG_over_HTTP mentions three:

1. MJPG-Streamer: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mjpg-streamer/
2. ffmpeg-server as part of ffmpeg http://www.ffmpeg.org/
3. cambozola http://www.charliemouse.com:8080/code/cambozola/

This is what I personally found out:

- MJPG-Streamer will only compile on linux flavors (does not compile e.g. on MacOS X)
- ffmpeg-server on ubuntu if installed with apt-get install is likely outdated and buggy
- Cambozola seems to be more like a standalone client